# XML XSL get attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have something like the following xml file. I need to get the member name using xsl.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="styleSheet.xsl"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>AlienRFID2</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:nsAlienRFID2.AlienDataDirector">
            <summary>
            EXPERIMENTAL.  Objects of this class may be used for sending Alien reader's messages to an external listener.
            Typical use of this class is by a mobile device, which is listening for Alien reader's notifications using CAlienServer objects and 
            wants to transfer those to a host (target) computer.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:nsAlienRFID2.AlienDataDirector.#ctor(System.Int32,System.Net.IPAddress,System.Boolean)">
            <summary>
            Creates instance for connecting to specified host server.
            </summary>
            <param name="targetPort">Network port value for connecting to host (target.)</param>
            <param name="targetIPAddress">IPAddress value for connecting to host (target.)</param>
            <param name="log">TRUE for turning internal API logging ON, FALSE otherwise.</param>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

I need to spit out the 'T:nsAlientFRID2.Alien...' and the 'M;nsAlienRFID2.Alien...' "member name" strings to a browser.  I understand its something like xsl: value-of select= "member/@name" but i can't get any variation of this to work. And i can't find a clear example of how to get attribute in quotes. Could someone help me out with an example?? THANKS!

edit ..i'm currently trying this code, but it spits out the summaries and not the attribute 'name'.

```
 <xsl:for-each select = "doc/members/member">             
      <xsl:value-of select = "@name"/>           
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: How would your desired output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this stylesheet named `styleSheet.xsl` matching the element and then getting the attribute's value with an `xsl:value-of`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="doc/members/member">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name" /><br />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- suppress other text nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then you can format the output as you like.

**Output:**

```
T:nsAlienRFID2.AlienDataDirector
M:nsAlienRFID2.AlienDataDirector.#ctor(System.Int32,System.Net.IPAddress,System.Boolean)
```